# Clean a Series or DataFrame of values, according to condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

Good Morning,
I have a Series like the following.

```
Time Temperature
2019-01-02 02:00:00 14.95
2019-01-02 03:00:00 15.0
2019-01-02 04:00:00 37.0
2019-01-02 05:00:00 15.0
2019-01-02 06:00:00 15.5
```

I would like to replace all values that do not follow the trend with a NAN. (e.g. the value 37). I was thinking of inserting a condition that considers the value in the previous row. But I don't know if there is a faster way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) to get the values not following the trend (=peaks). `find_peaks` offers a variety of methods to define what is a peak.

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

temp = df.Temperature.to_numpy()
idx, _ = find_peaks(temp, threshold=5)
temp[idx] = np.nan

df.Temperature = temp
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to implement this function but I don't understand how it works. If you have any useful links, I would be happy to look into them.

Comment: For `find_peaks` itself see the linked docs (as well as [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences) to understand what peak prominence is). `find_peaks` returns the indices of the peaks which can be used for [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) the numpy array. As a last step, we re-assign the array to the column.

Comment: This is a nice answer - I like the link to peak_prominence too - with those combined it should suit a wide range of what constitutes not "following the trend"

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply:

```py
df.loc[df.Temperature - df.Temperature.shift(-1) > 0, 'Temperature'] = np.nan
```

df:

```py
Time    Temperature
2019-01-02 02:00:00 14.95
2019-01-02 03:00:00 15.00
2019-01-02 04:00:00 NaN
2019-01-02 05:00:00 15.00
2019-01-02 06:00:00 15.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define more tightly what you mean by "follow the trend", but I'll give an example for, say, a point that is more than 1.5 times the mean of points within a 5 timeslot window.

You could use [pandas Series.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to get a local rolling mean and then use pandas series slice indexing to apply the condition.

```py
# Make some random data with an outlier
data_points = 48
random_data = np.random.random(data_points)
temps = random_data * 2 + 14
temps[6] = 37.0
times = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-02 02:00:00", freq="H", periods=data_points)

s = pd.Series(data=temps, index=times)

# See data with the outlier
print(s)

# Use pandas Series.rolling() to find local rolling mean
rolling_mean = s.rolling(5,min_periods=1,center=True).mean()

# Use Pandas slice indesxing to alter only values > 1.5 times the rolling mean
s[s > rolling_mean * 1.5]=float("NaN")

# Outlier replaced with NaN
print(s)
```